# dynamic adding of data to JSON

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

So what I'm trying to do is storing the dataUri of pictures in my localstorage. I am only using javascript and angularJS. No jQuery at this point.

The pictures are uploaded through inputs of **type="file"** with ids like "**input_file_0**" and so on.

I am able to store the id and the dataUri in my $scope.files variable. So that if I say `console.log($scope.files);` I get an output like this:

### $scope.files

```
< [input_file_0:File, input_file_1:File, ...]
  length:0
  < input_file_0:File
       lastModified: 1457515898145
       lastModifiedDate: Wed Mar 09 2016 10:31:38 GMT+0100 
       name: "name-of-picture.png"
       size: 206156
       src:  "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K..."
       type: "image/png"

  > input_file_1:File
```

### controller.js

```
/*
 * stores $scope-values for longer reference in the localStorage
 * @returns {undefined}
 */
    $scope.storeDataInLocalStorage = function () {
        if (typeof (localStorage) !== 'undefined') {
            //storing file data
            var data = {};
            for (var i = 0; i <= $scope.files.length; i++) {
                data.push({ 'file_input_'+i : $scope.files['file_input_'+i].src}) ;
            }
            localStorage.setItem('files', JSON.stringify(data));
        }
        /* No localstorage support */
        else {
            alert("Sorry. Localstorage is not supported");
        }
    };
```

---

### I want to achieve a localStorage item like this:

```
localStorage.getItem('files') = 
{'input_file_0' : "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K...", 
 'input_file_1 : "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K..."}
```

But setting the key just doesn't work. Getting the src-attribute works just fine. But having a variable to be the key doesn't work. It always substitutes it with just the variablename.

---

Comment: There is a good one library for localStorage in Angular. **https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage** You can store key value pair using this.

Comment: Thx, maybe that gives me a better and easier way to do this using angularJS

Comment: Welcome. Hope it solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself trying something I tried before that didn't work and now suddenly does. Maybe there was something already stored locally and i didnt' delete it correctly.

I didn't use push this time and so my code looks like this:

### controller.js

```
/*
 * stores $scope-values for longer reference in the localStorage
 * @returns {undefined}
 */
    $scope.storeDataInLocalStorage = function () {
        if (typeof (localStorage) !== 'undefined') {
            //storing file data
            var data = {};
            for (var i = 0; i <= $scope.files.length; i++) {

                data['input_file_'+i]= $scope.data['input_file_'+i].src;

            }
            localStorage.setItem('files', JSON.stringify(data));
        }
        /* No localstorage support */
        else {
            alert("Sorry. Localstorage is not supported");
        }
    };
```

still anyone an idea how to do it using `array.push()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use extra object to add items in for loop:

```
  var data = [];
  for (var i = 0; i <= $scope.files.length; i++) {
        var o = {};
        o[('file_input_' + i)] = $scope.files['file_input_'+i].src;
        data.push(o);
   }
  localStorage.setItem('files', JSON.stringify(data));
```

Comment: Thx, that works perfectly once I changed my data-constructor to the [ ] braces.

Comment: Just saw, that I now have an object like this:
`localStorage.getItem('files') = [{'input_file_0' : "data...", ... }]`
So to get to the data I have to do sth like this  `files.[0][input_file_0]`

Comment: I guess yes, that fits you data structure better